# Making a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

This is a code to make a linked list with 2 values- one user input and another 7.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class node{
public:
    node();
    ~node();
    void printList();
    void insert_front(int);
    void delete_front();
private:
    int data;
    node *head;
    node *next;
};
node::node()
{
    head=NULL;
}
node::~node( ){//destructor
    cout <<"destructor called";
    while( head!= NULL) delete_front() ;
}
void node::delete_front(){
    node *h=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<< "Empty List.\n";
        return;
    }
    head = head->next;
    delete(h);
}
void node::printList()
{
    node *h=head;
    cout<< "Printing the list";
    while(h!=NULL)
    {
        cout<< h->data;
        cout<< '\n';
        h->next= h->next->next;
    }
}
void node::insert_front(int value){
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->data=value;
    temp -> next = NULL;
    if (head != NULL){
        temp->next =head;
    }
    head= temp;
}

int main()
{
    node ListX;
    cout<< "enter integer";
    int as;
    cin>> as;
    ListX.insert_front(as);
    ListX.insert_front(7);
    ListX.printList();
    ListX.~node( );//call destructor to free objects
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell the error in this as it shows an error while compiling it online on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php and even on my laptop.

Comment: So, what is not working?

Comment: It shows *what* error? And you shouldn't be calling the destructor.

Comment: it does not show an error. But it keeps compiling for ever. Not calling the destructor made no difference.

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc I would say the online compiler has an error.

Comment: cant understand how to install gcc on windows.

Comment: Interesting bit of logic you have their on the marriage of the destructor with `delete_front()`. You may want to think about that awhile longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`h->next= h->next->next;`

What are you trying to achieve here ?

Change `while` loop in `void node::printList()` to:

```
while(h!=NULL)
{
  cout<< h->data;
  cout<< '\n';
  h= h->next;
}
```